# RegEx - String Help - Stata

Tags: regex, string, stata

I have data in the form of

name1, name2, name3, name4

all in one column. I'm trying to separate all names into their own columns.

So far I have:

```
gen Songwriter1 = regexs(1) if regexm(Songwriter, "(.*)[,]")
```

which gives all values before the ","

Is there a way to specify that I want the value between the first "," and the second ","? And so forth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Stata 8 or later you could try:

```
split Songwriter, p(,)
```

`split` given `Songwriter` and `p(,)` will parse (split) on commas and throw those commas away. It will create `Songwriter1`, `Songwriter2`, etc.